# Sqoop import to HCatalog/Hive - table not visible

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform, hcatalog

HDP-2.4.2.0-258 installed using Ambari 2.2.2.0

I have to import several SQL Server schema which should be accessible via Hive, Pig, MR and any third party(in future). I decided to import in HCatalog.

Sqoop provides ways to import to Hive OR HCatalog, I guess if I import to HCatalog, the same table will be accessible from Hive CLI, to MR and to Pig(please evaluate my assumption).

Questions :

- If imported to Hive directly, will the table be available to Pig, MR
  ?
- If imported to HCatalog, what needs to be done for accessing via Hive ?
- Is pre-creation of tables in Hive necessary ? If yes, what is the advantage of the importing in HCatalog, (I can import in Hive directly)/(import in HDFS and then create external table) ?

**Issue** :
I wish to achieve the following in one step :

- Import of the data(from SQL Server tables)
- Avoid 'pre-creating' or writing create statements for those tables(there are 100s of them)
- Store the table in ORC format
- Store this data at custom HDFS path say /org/data/schema1, /org/data/schema2 and so on(is this impossible because Sqoop says it (--target-dir/--warehouse-dir)

I executed the following command :

```
-bash-4.2$ sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<IP>;database=FleetManagement' --username --password  --table SettingAttribute -- --schema Administration  --hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat --hcatalog-database default --hcatalog-table SettingAttribute --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile"
```

The source table contains 109 records and those are fetched :

```
16/08/10 15:02:27 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.2.0-258
16/08/10 15:02:27 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/08/10 15:02:28 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/08/10 15:02:28 INFO manager.SQLServerManager: We will use schema Administration
16/08/10 15:02:28 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/08/10 15:02:28 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [Administration].[SettingAttribute] AS t WHERE 1=0
16/08/10 15:02:28 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-ojoqcu/compile/dfab14748c41a566ec286b7e4b11004d/SettingAttribute.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/08/10 15:02:30 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-ojoqcu/compile/dfab14748c41a566ec286b7e4b11004d/SettingAttribute.jar
16/08/10 15:02:30 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of SettingAttribute
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/accumulo/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/08/10 15:02:31 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://l4373t.sss.com:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
16/08/10 15:02:31 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at l4283t.sss.com/138.106.9.80:8050
16/08/10 15:02:33 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
16/08/10 15:02:33 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN([SettingAttributeId]), MAX([SettingAttributeId]) FROM [Administration].[SettingAttribute]
16/08/10 15:02:33 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
16/08/10 15:02:33 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1467787344827_0013
16/08/10 15:02:34 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1467787344827_0013
16/08/10 15:02:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://l4283t.sss.com:8088/proxy/application_1467787344827_0013/
16/08/10 15:02:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1467787344827_0013
16/08/10 15:02:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1467787344827_0013 running in uber mode : false
16/08/10 15:02:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/08/10 15:02:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/08/10 15:02:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1467787344827_0013 completed successfully
16/08/10 15:02:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=0
                FILE: Number of bytes written=616636
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=540
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=10079
                HDFS: Number of read operations=16
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=8
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=4
                Other local map tasks=4
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=16132
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=16132
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=16132
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=66076672
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=109
                Map output records=109
                Input split bytes=540
                Spilled Records=0
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=320
                CPU time spent (ms)=6340
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=999870464
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=21872697344
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=943194112
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=10079
16/08/10 15:02:48 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 9.8428 KB in 17.2115 seconds (585.597 bytes/sec)
16/08/10 15:02:48 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 109 records.
```

The files are created under my user :

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/ojoqcu/SettingAttribute
Found 5 items
-rw-------   3 ojoqcu hdfs          0 2016-08-10 15:02 /user/ojoqcu/SettingAttribute/_SUCCESS
-rw-------   3 ojoqcu hdfs       8378 2016-08-10 15:02 /user/ojoqcu/SettingAttribute/part-m-00000
-rw-------   3 ojoqcu hdfs        144 2016-08-10 15:02 /user/ojoqcu/SettingAttribute/part-m-00001
-rw-------   3 ojoqcu hdfs       1123 2016-08-10 15:02 /user/ojoqcu/SettingAttribute/part-m-00002
-rw-------   3 ojoqcu hdfs        434 2016-08-10 15:02 /user/ojoqcu/SettingAttribute/part-m-00003
```

I cannot see anything in HCatalog(nor in Hive)

```
-bash-4.2$ /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hive-hcatalog/bin/hcat -e "show tables in default;"
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
16/08/10 15:07:12 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
OK
Time taken: 2.007 seconds
```

***Is there some authorization issue ?***

I checked the var/log but none exist for Sqoop, Hive-Hcatalog and Hive, how can I view the authorization issue and fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm unsure whether it was an authorization issue or a mere parsing problem or both. I did the following and it worked :

1. Did an `su hive`
2. Executed the following command(probably, the `-- --schema` should be
   the last arg, Sqoop simply ignores/breaks after that!)

   `sqoop import --hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat --hcatalog-database FleetManagement_Ape --hcatalog-table DatabaseLog --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile" --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<IP>;database=FleetManagement' --username  --password  --table DatabaseLog -- --schema ape`

Comment: @dev thanks for the edit, I was unable to format the code :)