# Sqoop create-hive-table SQL Server NON-DEFAULT schema

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

HDP-2.4.2.0-258 installed using Ambari 2.2.2.0

In SQL Server :

```
TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA        TABLE_NAME
Management  Administration      SettingAttribute
Management  Administration      SettingAttributeGroup
Management  Administration      SettingAttributeValue
Management  Administration      SettingValue
Management  ape                 DatabaseScriptLog
Management  ape                 DatabaseLog
Management  Common              Language
Management  Common              ThirdPartyType
Management  Common              Country
Management  Company             DistributorCow
Management  Company             CustomerSetting
Management  Company             CustomerSettingAttributeValue
```

I can list the databases and the tables in a schema :

```
-bash-4.2$ sqoop list-databases --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<IP>;database=FleetManagement' --username --password 
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
16/08/11 11:25:39 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.2.0-258
16/08/11 11:25:39 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/08/11 11:25:39 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
master
tempdb
model
msdb
Auth
FeatureToggle
FleetManagementCoach
LatestRuntime
FleetManagementThirdParty
VehicleDriverServicesFollowUp
FleetManagementCustomer
FleetManagementMessaging
FleetManagementSubscription
FleetManagementSupport
FleetManagementFollowUp
FleetManagementDatawarehouse
FleetManagement
FleetManagementPositioning

-bash-4.2$ sqoop list-tables --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<IP>;database=FleetManagement' --username --password  -- --schema Administration
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
16/08/11 11:25:12 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.2.0-258
16/08/11 11:25:12 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/08/11 11:25:12 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/08/11 11:25:12 INFO manager.SQLServerManager: We will use schema Administration
SettingAttribute
SettingAttributeGroup
SettingAttributeValue
SettingValue
```

Now, while using create-hive-table, Sqoop is unable to create SettingAttribute table

I tried the following commands in vain :

```
sqoop create-hive-table --driver 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<IP>;database=FleetManagement' --username  --password  --table 'Administration.SettingAttribute'
```

The output :

```
16/08/10 16:40:32 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.2.0-258
16/08/10 16:40:32 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/08/10 16:40:32 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
16/08/10 16:40:32 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
16/08/10 16:40:32 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/08/10 16:40:33 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [Administration.SettingAttribute] AS t WHERE 1=0
16/08/10 16:40:33 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'Administration.SettingAttribute'.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'Administration.SettingAttribute'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:440)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2444)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:297)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:758)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.hive.TableDefWriter.getCreateTableStmt(TableDefWriter.java:126)
        at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:188)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CreateHiveTableTool.run(CreateHiveTableTool.java:58)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/accumulo/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/08/10 16:40:34 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive
16/08/10 16:40:34 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-258.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
NoViableAltException(307@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.identifier(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:11578)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.identifier(HiveParser.java:45881)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:38052)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeList(HiveParser.java:36183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:5222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2648)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1658)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:684)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:624)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:338)
        at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:245)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CreateHiveTableTool.run(CreateHiveTableTool.java:58)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:63 cannot recognize input near ')' 'COMMENT' ''Imported by sqoop on 2016/08/10 16:40:33'' in column specification
```

Even this one failed :

```
sqoop create-hive-table --driver 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<IP>;database=FleetManagement' -- --schema Administration --table 'SettingAttribute' --username  --password
```

The output :

```
16/08/10 16:42:37 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.2.0-258
16/08/10 16:42:37 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for create-hive-table:
16/08/10 16:42:37 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --
16/08/10 16:42:37 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --schema
16/08/10 16:42:37 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: Administration
16/08/10 16:42:37 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --table
16/08/10 16:42:37 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: SettingAttribute
16/08/10 16:42:37 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --username
```

Doesn't the create-hive-table support --schema option(nothing mentioned in the [documentation](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_create_hive_table_literal))

Comment: What is your empty '--' means? I assume you specify username and password parameters values?

Comment: Well, that's a strange syntax(-- --schema) I had to use while listing tables in a non-default SQL Server schema, for details, you can refer :
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/50557/sqoop-import-sql-server-non-default-schema.html

That doesn't work with HCatalog import ...

Comment: Do you have an access to the tables and schemas from the user you are working with? You can check it with sqoop-list-database and sqoop-list-tables commands

Comment: Yeah I edited my question to include that, if I do a sqoop import to HCatalog, the files get created onto HDFS but the HCatalog table is not created but I think then I have the right access, however, that's a different issue :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891139/sqoop-import-to-hcatalog-hive-table-not-visible

Answer (score 0):

use.. "-- --schema" at the end of the statement.

sqoop create-hive-table --driver 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://;database=FleetManagement' --table 'SettingAttribute' --username  --password  -- --schema Administration